# Why is my PrintDialog always opening "save as" and not print directly?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, printdialog

So I have an Window which I want to Print. For that I created an Print Dialog. Which looks like that:

```
 PrinterSettings settings = new PrinterSettings();
        string Printer = settings.PrinterName;

        System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog printDlg = new System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog();
      

        printDlg.PrintQueue = new PrintQueue(new PrintServer(), Printer);
        printDlg.PrintTicket.CopyCount = 1;
        printDlg.PrintTicket.PageOrientation = PageOrientation.Landscape;
        printDlg.PrintVisual(this, "Window Printing.");
```

But for some reason it opens instant an Dialog for save that Programm as PDF. But I want directly print it to my Printer, without that Dialog. So why does it not Print to my Printer? And how Can I get this to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you have chosen the correct printer? Because the `PrintDialog` will behave like this if its printer is set to a file printer, for example to: `"Microsoft Print to PDF"`. (Then, obviously, you have to provide the name of the file the printer should print to, hence the "save" dialog.)

Check what printers you have installed (or rather, what `PrintQueues` you have available):

```
LocalPrintServer myPrintServer = new LocalPrintServer();
foreach (PrintQueue pq in myPrintServer.GetPrintQueues())
{
     Console.WriteLine(pq.Name);
}
```

Are you sure you're setting one of those? Which one is the default in your system? Is it maybe a file printer?

Try setting a printer name to the correct, physical printer in code, and check if anything will print:

```
string myPrinterName = "My Printer"; // <= put an existing name here

LocalPrintServer myPrintServer = new LocalPrintServer();
PrintDialog printDlg = new PrintDialog();  

PrintQueue printQueue = myPrintServer.GetPrintQueue(myPrinterName);
        
printDlg.PrintQueue = printQueue;
printDlg.PrintTicket.CopyCount = 1;
printDlg.PrintTicket.PageOrientation = PageOrientation.Landscape;
 
printDlg.PrintVisual(this, "Window Printing.");
```

In the system, is the printer configured correctly?